# Android get Exif information issue

Tags: android, exif, exificient

In order to get Exif information of image,I wrote some codes like below:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
String aaa= (exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME));
```

I also add read,write permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now the problem is for some specific folder, such as
/storage/emultaed/0/Pictures,/storage/emultaed/0/Download,
the return values of exif.getAttribute(...) are null.

I am wondering if there any 3rd party lib that can solve this issue? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Some pictures work fine - so the problem was the data, not your code. I suspect some devices/applications encode their exif data in a non-standard way that ExifInterface cannot parse.
You can use [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to dump the EXIF, and modify and standardise it

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several possible date-time values in Exif. Not all images contain exposure times either.

I maintain a Java `metadata-extractor` library which has great support for Exif and other types of metadata, and a simple API. If exiftool finds a date-time in your image files, then `metadata-extractor` will give you access to it.

Take a look on GitHub. It's available via Maven as well.

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor